# NextJS Custom Image Loader - Not Applied

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to mage custom loader for NextJS.
But when I implement it, it returns error like below:

```
Error: Image with src "/image/logo.png" is missing "loader" prop.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-missing-loader
```

My next.config.js file:

```
module.exports =
  {
    images: {
      loader: 'custom',
      loaderFile: './optimization/loader.js',
    },
```

that file is located on root directory. projectname/optimization/loader.js

```
export default function customImageLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
    return `https://blabla/${width}x/${height}/${src}?q=${quality || 75}`
}
```

Which configuration is wrong?
I've applied exact the same steps on documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-image-loader-config

Why it doesnt work? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an older version of Next.js, as the loaderFile feature is only available from Next.js 13 onwards. You can use this library as a replacement: https://github.com/aiji42/next-image-loader.